# Testing an IRC bot

Tags: python, testing, connection, irc, bots

I am writing an IRC bot in Python using the Twisted library. To test my bot I need to connect several times to an IRC network as my bot requires a restart each time a change is made. Therefore I am often "banned" from these networks for a couple of minutes because I have made a lot of connections.
This makes it annoying testing and writing the bot. Does anyone know of a better way to test the bot or any network which isn't as restrict with the amount of connections as QuakeNet is?

Comment: Doesn't Python have a command to reload source file? My Ruby bot uses `Kernel#load`, when I tell him *rehash*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [UnrealIRCd](http://www.unrealircd.com/) (it's an irc server) on your local machine and test your bot with it. Any network will ban you if you keep reconnecting all the time. Plus working against a local server will speed up the connection times alot.

There are a bunch of other irc servers out [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_daemons).

+1 for supy bot.

Answer (score 0):

freenode is good..  You can create channels for yourself to test.  Also check out this project called supybot, which is good for Python bots.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the undernet ircu from http://coder-com.undernet.org and, before compiling it, add `#define NOTHROTTLE` to `ircd_defs.h`. This will remove any connection throttling so you can test your bot as much as you want.